# Placing a point among Line Segments - An algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to solve a problem, where in given a large number of line segments, I have to try to optimally place a point such that the total distance from every line to the point is minimised(i.e find an optimum location) . the point line distance can be from anywhere on a line to the point ,also the distance can be calculated through other line segments( say there are two lines , (0,0) to (0,1) and (1,0) to (1,1) and my point is say (2,0.5), I can calculate the distance to the first line "through" the second line , I hope I am clear enough ). The lines all have integer coordinates as end points, but the point can lie anywhere on the plane.

I have thought a lot about this, but am unable to come up with a general strategy. Could someone please point me to some reading material or explain an algorithm for this? I've seen something like this elsewhere , so is this some sort of general class of problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Your example would have an infinite number of points, as the two lines are parallel and any point from [0,.5] to [1,.5] will be .5 from each line. Am I misinterpreting your example (and therefore question)?

Comment: i just gave that example to demonstrate that distances can be calculated "through" other lines. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Clarification: are you computing the distance from the point to the line as the (Euclidean) length of the segment going from the line to the segment, perpendicular to that line? Asking because if that's the case it doesn't matter whether the lines have integer coordinates - your pairs of points are vectors that define the direction of the lines.

Comment: Distance from point to *line* and distance from point to *line segment* are not the same thing. It is not clear which one do you want to minimize. The corresponding problems are very different.

Comment: @n.m I wish to minimize the distance to the line segment. Sorry for the loose english :P.

Comment: So your distance is the distance to the closest point on the segment?

Comment: @Mathias. Yes that is the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the shortest line distance need be discussed separately based on the *zone* defined by the line segment. For example, if the line segment is (0,0) to (0,1), then we must slice the space into three sub-spaces (d denotes the minimum distance function):

- y < 0: d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
- 0 < y < 1: d = |x| (*zone* defined by this line segment)
- 1 < y: d = sqrt(x^2 + (y-1)^2)

The function d has the [convex property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), therefore you can solve the optimization problem by running though some standard convex optimization software, [cvx package](http://cvxr.com/cvx/download/) is a good one. For more information on convex optimization theory, [convex optimization](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) is a good book to refer to.

---

If you don't bother to go though some optimization solver to get the result, solving an alternative version based on heuristic can be much simpler.

Notice that the problem would be trivial if line segments extend indefinitely on both ends. So what I can think of is to treat the segments *as if* they are lines, but add a penalty  distance to the end points. With that said, the following metric satisfy the need:

L = [(ax + by - c)^2] + [(x-x1)^2 + (x-y1)^2] + [(x-x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2]

here (x, y) is the point you need to decide, ax* + by* = c defines the line, (x1,y1), (x2,y2) is the two end points. Therefore the 1st [...] term is the squared distance to the line; 2nd and 3rd [...] term is the squared distance to the two end points.

Minimize L means:

- Prefer to relies on or close to the line;
- Prefer to resides in the *zone* defined by the segment;

It falls into *least square distance* problem, so you can get the solution by simply solving a set of linear equations. This is also the very reason I stick to quadratic form in L.

Of course this is just a heuristic method that leads to simpler solution. Other formulations of the term L might lead to better outcome, in terms of visual cognition. You might consider play with different L's, and then choose the best one based on visual outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have an algorithm that works, ( i found it on Google) , its seems crazy that it would work . Could someone please give me an explanation as to why it does? Thanks..

```
 To solve this, we start by placing the point at any random location and moving 
 it around in various directions, decreasing the amount that we move it by.To begin
 place the point at any location. Next move it in large increments (20) about
 10 times.Now we decrease the amount by which we move by an amount to 1/10;Running 
 the whole placement process about 5   times, decreasing the amount by
 which we move the power source each time, will give us the best location 
 for the point.
```

Comment: I know it does work because it does work for some sample inputs that i have

Comment: I assume you are not moving the point completely randomly, but trying random directions and picking the best one? This may work, because I think the distance is convex, and has a single best point, so as long as you are improving at each step you are progressing towards the unique best position. This method should not give you a perfect solution, though, but should converge close to the true optimum.

Comment: Yes, I am picking the best direction at each time. Hmm I get where you are going with the explanation.

Comment: This will often work, edpecially for simple inputs, but not necessarily always. It is something very like the [gradient descent method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). It will find a local minimum which does mot necessarily coincide with the global one.